# Does azure cosmosdb have like any operator to find records matching a pattern

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am just wondering how do I do the below using the SQL API on Azure CosmosDB -

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id LIKE ANY(contacts);
```

The above statement works on postgres, wondering if there is anything similar in Azure CosmosDB.

The above statement receives a set of contacts in an array format like this ["4160000000","7780000000"] and finds the corresponding records in Postgres db.

UPDATE @Sajeetharan

Below are the documents I have in Cosmos DB-

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "14161231234",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 1"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "18055678978",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 2"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "17202228799",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 3"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "17780265987",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I will be sending in a set of userPhoneNumbers from javascript in an array format like below and then I need the SQL query to return the corresponding records in cosmos db.

```
var userPhoneNumbers = ["4161231234","7202228799"];
```

The above array has two values, which when sent to the cosmosdb should return the first and third record.

The userPhoneNumbers sent in will be sometimes missing the country code, so the search should be performed using CONTAINS or ENDSWITH.

**UPDATE APRIL 4th 2023 - After trying out RitikaNalwayas answer**

I tried out your user defined function with the Select statement that you provided but the result I get is

[image] -

USER DEFINED FUNCTION

```
function findUserNameByPhone(users, userPhoneNumbers) {
    var s, i, j;
    let result = [];
    for(j = 0; j < userPhoneNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) 
        {
            s = users[i];
            if(s.userPhoneNumber.match(userPhoneNumbers[j]))
                result.push(s)
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

SELECT STATEMENT

```
SELECT DISTINCT udf.findUserByPhoneNumber(c,'14161231234','17780000000']) FROM c
```

Now if I console log the users array that the function is receiving it is in the below format -
[
{
"$1": {
"partitionKey": "user",
"userPhoneNumber": "14161231234",
"userDisplayName": "Test User 1",
}
},
{
"$1": {
"partitionKey": "user",
"userPhoneNumber": "18055678978",
"userDisplayName": "Test User 2",
}
}
]

I am not understanding what the $1 is and if that has anything to do with the result. I have tried the above code on code editor outside of azure portal where I am able to get the right results.

I have also added $1 to the match statement inside the If condition like below, still I don't get any results. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
if(s.$1.userPhoneNumber.match(userPhoneNumbers[j]))
```

**UPDATE - April 24th 2023 after trying out the query from the RitikaNalwayas latest comment**

This is what SELECT * FROM c returns

```
[
    {
        "partitionKey": "user",
        "userPhoneNumber": "14161231234",
        "userDisplayName": "User 1",
    },
    {
        "partitionKey": "user",
        "userPhoneNumber": "18055678978",
        "userDisplayName": "User 2",
    },
    {
        "partitionKey": "user",
        "userPhoneNumber": "17202228799",
        "userDisplayName": "User 3",
    }
]
```

Here is my latest user defined function -

```
function findUserNameByPhone(users, userPhoneNumbers) {
    var s, i, j;
    let result = [];
    for(j = 0; j < userPhoneNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) 
        {
            s = users[i];
            if(s.userPhoneNumber.match(userPhoneNumbers[j]))
                result.push(s)
        }
    }    
    return result
}
```

SELECT Query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT udf.findUserByPhoneNumber(c.users,'14161231234','17780000000']) FROM c
```

This is what I get returned -

```
[
     {}
]
```

---

UPDATE - 26th APRIL 2023

Upon doing some analysis I found that just printing out the length of the retrieved users array returns nothing, in that case how would looping through the users array work? There is something weird that is happening which I am not aware of.

```
function findUserNameByPhone(users, userPhoneNumbers) {
    var s, i, j;
    let result = [];
    var x = users.length
    
    return x;
}
```

Comment: ARRAY_CONTAINS might be what you're looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/array-contains

Comment: Can you provide a sample document if you are looking for an exact query?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I have updated the original post with the extra data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per cosmos technical support, using user defined function is not recommended  as udf's dont utilize indexes so performance will be really poor. The tech support recommends using the ENDSWITH function with the OR operator to pull the required data.

So in the scenario I could do a query construction with the all phone numbers received and send in that query to cosmos db.

The below code is in python -

```
def resolve_users(_, info):
    phones = ["14161231234", "7202228799"]
    query = "SELECT c.id, c.userPhoneNumber, c.userDisplayName FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'user' AND ("

    for p in range(0, len(phones)):
        if p + 1 != len(phones):
            query += "ENDSWITH(c.userPhoneNumber,'"+phones[p]+"') OR "
        else:
            query += "ENDSWITH(c.userPhoneNumber,'"+phones[p]+"'))"

    items = list(container.query_items(
        query=query,
        enable_cross_partition_query=True
    ))
    return items
```

The above code would produce a query like below -

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'user' AND (ENDSWITH(c.userPhoneNumber,'4161231234') OR ENDSWITH(c.userPhoneNumber,'7202228799'))
```

I am super happy as I was able to finally get an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in question, need to perform like operation on phone numbers passing as array.
In cosmosDb there is no in-built function helps us to achieve the result. The way to achieve expected result is using cosmosDb UDF. Below is code snippet for the same.

```
function findUserNameByPhone(users, userPhoneNumbers) {
    var s, i, j;
    let result = [];
    for(j = 0; j < userPhoneNumbers.length; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) 
        {
            s = users[i];
            if(s.userPhoneNumber.match(userPhoneNumbers[j]))
                result = result.concat(s);
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

Consume the udf in query :-

```
SELECT udf.findUserNameByPhone(c.users,["4161231234","7202228799"]) FROM c
```

**Edit as per comment**

Use the UDF in select query. Also, as per your latest comment, if you need the result based on specific partition key you can use the self join as shown in the updated query. As `partitionKey` property is part of `users` array, hence the self join by passing the partitionKey value in where clause.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT udf.findUserNameByPhone(c.users,["4161231234","7202228799"]) FROM c
JOIN u in c.users WHERE u.partitionKey = "user"
```

Consuming parameterized queries in Cosmos DB using Node.js check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/samples/ItemManagement.ts#L58-L79)

Comment: Thanks @RitikaNalwaya for providing a clarity on what I am looking for. Mine is a single table design which means I will be having the users data along with other records in a single table. How do I got about querying only records that has the partitionKey set to user?

Comment: @Sumchans Updated the answer by querying records on basis of partitionKey.

Comment: Thanks for the update here. I yet have to try your latest update. I am wondering if the latest code would only return the phonenumbers that has a match in the database. The first statement returned me same number of records equivalent to the number of records in the database.

Comment: @Sumchans For me it's just returning only matching records but if it's returning you same number of records equivalents to the number of records in the database then may be using `DISTINCT` keyword will help you. Please check the part of answer mentioned as "Edit as per comment".

Comment: Sorry Ritika, I was away for two months. I just added a few updates after trying out the function to the original post. Unfortunately I am getting zero results.

Comment: @Sumchans, my apologies for delay in response. As I can see your input array data stored in `"users"`. And while querying UDF you are just passing c. Can you please update first argument of the UDF `c` to `c.users`. Here is updated query `SELECT DISTINCT udf.findUserByPhoneNumber(c.users,'14161231234','17780000000']) FROM c`

Comment: I tried the above mentioned query I still don't get any results returned. I have modified my original post to add details from my other post.

Comment: Also regarding adding users to the select statement, there is no user tag returned when I do  SELECT * FROM c

Comment: @Sumchans can you please confirm about your input data, first time the complete collection was part of `users` then in recent update on 24th April its showing there is no `users`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM c does not return the data with the users tag. It returns the data exactly as you see on my latest update.

Comment: @Sumchans I am using the input data posted in question and the UDF posted in answer and able to get the data. Here is the [output](https://i.imgur.com/k2ejlCo.png) of the query.

Comment: Did you use the input data without the users tag? I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I still dont get results. Could you explain what $1 means in the result set?

Comment: I just did some analysis and found out that just printing the length of the users array returns nothing. How is the for loop supposed to work then? Details added to the original post.

Comment: This is so weird that you are getting the expected result but I am not. I am so fed up with this.

Comment: @Sumchans I have used input data with `users` tag (same as you posted first time in your question.) and Cosmos DB will not allow us to save any document with array without property name. Like in your input data array property name is `users`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253341/discussion-between-ritikanalwaya-and-sumchans).

Comment: I am available on chat now.